# How to write microservices with CQRS pattern in NestJs

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I have implemented CQRS pattern following the [CQRS recipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs).
I have a command like this:

#### src/commands/place-order.command.ts

```ts
import { ICommand } from '@nestjs/cqrs';

export class PlaceOrderCommand implements ICommand {
    constructor(public readonly order: Order) {}    
}
```

And a command handler:

#### src/command/place-order.handler.ts

```ts
import { ICommandHandler, CommandHandler, EventBus } from '@nestjs/cqrs';

@CommandHandler(PlaceOrderCommand)
export class PlaceOrderHandler implements ICommandHandler {
    constructor(private eventbus: EventBus) {}

    async execute(command: PlaceOrderCommand): Promise<any> {
        // Business logic here...

        // Publish event to notify case is created.
        this.eventbus.publish(orderPlacedEvent);
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, my event handler `OrderPlacedEventHandler` is in another microservice (invoice microservice). How do I ensure that my eventHandler listens to this `OrderPlacedEvent`?

#### In invoice microservice:

```ts
import { IEventHandler, EventsHandler} from '@nestjs/cqrs';

@EventsHandler(OrderPlacedEvent)
export class orderPlacedEventHandler implements IEventHandler<OrderPlacedEvent> {
    constructor(private commandbus: CommandBus) {}

    handle(event: OrderPlacedEvent) {
        // Business logic goes here...
    }
}
```